# When can you reorder log operations?

Tags: logistic-regression, mathematics, softmax

For example, you can reorder a ***softmax + nl (negative likelihood)***
 to  ***log_softmax + nll (negative log-likelihood)***

Essentially changing ***log(softmax(x))*** to ***softmax(log(x))***

However, what are the rules to reordering logging of things?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general, you cannot reorder like that. The example you give is a very special case that only works because *softmax* is based on the *exponential function*, which is the **inverse function** of the *natural logarithm*.